# Google assistant and node-red setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

Am a complete beginner in node-red and Java. I have been trying to follow the guide in this page to get Google action to connect to node red so that I can use it to control my devices as part of a school project. I am willing to learn.

Link: [node red Google action](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-google-action)

I've tried a lot over the past few days and learned the basics of express Web servers, ngrok, self encrypting node red and stuff but am still unable to establish the connection between node-red and Google action. Whenever I try to do so it just says that "test server is not responding, please try again later".

I've tried a lot but I'm sure I am still missing out some key things here. The first one is in the Google action input node, under port, url, ssl key and certificate I am unsure as to how I'm supposed to fill the values.

Second is I managed to have a Web server up and running through ngrok encrypted tunnel but I am not sure how I'm suppose to use it. (the Web server is just a blank https html page, or am I supposed to have something more?)

Am going to try assigning a domain name from noip to my Web server, encrypting it and port forward to 443. Do you think that's necessary and better?

Comment: Where you are running your instance of node-red, in the cloud or on your own machine? Since the node is running its own web server on a separate port, you would need to be running in an environment that allows this. Secondly this web server / port needs to be publicly assessable for the action to be triggered. These are conflicting requirements that would limit where you can actually run the application.

Comment: @chughts hi! It is running on my local machine. I've just managed to port forward into public Internet. Do u think now I'll be able to get the Google action node to work?

Comment: Don't know. Are you able to determine what port the  separate web server is configured for? Is that part of the node configuration?